# HTML CSS Align items of a div inline

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
  <div class="transparent" style="display: inline; text-align: justify; height: 80px;">
    <a style="padding: 4px">About Cilliai</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Advertise</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Manager</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Solutions</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Career</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Resources</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Contact</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Legal</a>
</div>
```

which gives the following output
[image: output]

Everything looks as expected but the I want the text signage solutions to be in the same line and shift legal to the next line. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

you could possible add clear: right to the last one this would allow you to achieve this outside of the normal text flow.

```
div a {
  float:left;
}
```

```
    <a style="padding: 4px">About Cilliai</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Advertise</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Manager</a>
    <a style="clear: right; padding: 4px">Signage Solutions</a> 
    <a style="padding: 4px">Career</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Resources</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Contact</a>
    <a style="clear:both; padding: 4px">Legal</a>
</div>
```

You will probably have to fiddle with the clear setting - left right or both to get it exactly right and perhaps also the order of your anchors

Answer (score 1):

Use display flex instead of display inline.

```
display: flex;
height: 80px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want some `<br>`?

How about [`word-wrap`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) ?

```css
div a {
  word-spacing: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent" style="display: inline; text-align: justify; height: 80px;">
    <a style="padding: 4px">About Cilliai</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Advertise</a> <br>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Manager</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Solutions</a> <br>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Career</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Resources</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Contact</a> <br>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Legal</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `</br>`this will add a new line break. If not try adding to the `<div style="width:100% "` or width:200px use the width to give space to the div in order to get the text beside each other. if the width is low the text will automatically get in a new line

Answer (score 0):

To the text of an `a` element on the same line add `white-space: nowrap;`

**Demo:**

```css
.transparent a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-left: solid 1px black;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width:400px"><!-- Purely to demonstrate wrap-->  
  <div class="transparent" style="display: inline; text-align: justify; height: 80px;">
    <a style="padding: 4px">About Cilliai</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Advertise</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Manager</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Solutions</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Career</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Resources</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Contact</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Legal</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.transparent
{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:40%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="transparent">
    <a style="padding: 4px">About Cilliai</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Advertise</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Manager</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Signage Solutions</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Career</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Resources</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Contact</a>
    <a style="padding: 4px">Legal</a>
</div>
```

Comment: use `flex-layout` instead of `display:inline`